# Tense system of passage

Tags: past-tense

Can one describe the following as using the Past Tense? I am not so sure.

> I shrugged. It was clear that we'd stumbled into a prehistoric
> gathering. The voice of a "drug expert" named Bloomquist crackled
> out of the nearby speakers: "... about these flashbacks, the
> patient never knows; he thinks it's all over  and he gets himself
> straightened out for six months . . . and then, darn it, the whole
> trip comes back on him."

Comment: Hi. Can you see any other tenses which are used?

Comment: There is a mix of past and present

Comment: And "we'd stumbled" is past perfect.

Answer (score 1):

> Can one describe the following as using the Past Tense?

Yes. There is use of the past tense in the extract:

> I **shrugged**. It **was** clear that we **'d stumbled** into a prehistoric gathering. The voice of a "drug expert" **named** Bloomquist **crackled** out of the nearby speakers:

This is all in the past tense. It is followed what Bloomquist said and that is given in direct speech. When he does this he uses the present tense as a generalisation

> "... about these flashbacks, the patient never **knows**; he **thinks** it**'s** all over and he **gets** himself **straightened out** (present causative) for six months . . . and then, darn it, the whole trip **comes** back on him."

As far as the analysis of the passage is concerned, the contents of what he said are not important because *crackled out of the nearby speakers: "... about these flashbacks, the patient never knows; he thinks it's all over and he gets himself straightened out for six months . . . and then, darn it, the whole trip comes back on him."* could be replaced by "and he said something".

Answer (score -1):

While the majority of the passage is in the past tense, there is a brief use of the simple present tense ("the patient never knows") within a past narrative context, which is a common narrative technique to make the description more immediate and engaging.

Comment: Actually, the present tense is used only in the passage of direct speech, where the speaker is making a generalisation.